# ssis not inserting all excel source into the ole db destination

Tags: ssis, business-intelligence

I am trying to import a data from 3 diffrent excel source to an OLE DB destination but only the data of one excel source appeare in the data base
knowing that all the excel source have data in it

[image]

Comment: I havent used ssis enough recently to know an answer for sure, but seeing as though no one else has answered yet- could you set up three Data flows, one for each worksheet and chain them together in the control flow to run one after the other. Also what happens in this Data Flow when you remove Depot2020? Do you only get 2021?